# Why is a user not a member of their private group (UPG) according to the GUI? (although CLI proves the opposite...)

Tags: users, user-management, groups

- I downloaded the current iso file of Ubuntu MATE from [the website](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/).
- I did a completely fresh install of Ubuntu MATE 16.04 (specifically 16.04.5).

  - the same is true for Ubuntu MATE 18.04 (specifically 18.04.1)
  - and [according to @mook765 also Ubuntu Studio 18.04 (Xfce) seems to be affected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069389/#comment1753765_1069389)
- I created a default user while installing with its GUI called `test` (full name *Test*). The system thus created a UPG called `test`.
- after installation had finished, I restarted the system.
- Now on the completely fresh system I open **System > Control Center > Users and Groups > Manage Groups**.
- I look for the `test` group and press **Properties**, and here it is... user `test` is not member of group `test`!

---

#### it looks like `/etc/group` suggests the same: (2nd last line)

```
test@test ~ $ less /etc/group | grep test
adm:x:4:syslog,test
cdrom:x:24:test
sudo:x:27:test
dip:x:30:test
plugdev:x:46:test
lpadmin:x:113:test
test:x:1000:
sambashare:x:129:test
```

but according to [how should `id` and `/etc/group` be read?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1069548/354350) the primary group of a user is only listed in `/etc/passwd` and not additional in `/etc/group` to avoid redundancy.

#### `id <username>` seems to suggest a little bit different:

```
test@test ~ $ id test
uid=1000(test) gid=1000(test) groups=1000(test),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),129(sambashare)
```

#### the best way to proof is `groups <username>`:

```
test@test ~ $ groups test
test : test adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

---

So is this a bug by the GUIs? - Somehow i doubt it, because of how long time it is there and also present in two well known DEs...

Comment: Whether a user gets assigned a UPG or not *at account creation* is determined by the `/etc/adduser.conf` settings (unless the account is created using lower-level means such as `useradd`) . What happens after that is up to the admin.

Comment: @steeldriver reads as an answer to me; besides maybe a remark that UPG is not used by default  ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind everything in the OP's terminal output says that user `test` *is* in group `test` (the UPG) - so I guess the question should really be why the GUI users-and-groups pane said something different?

Comment: I can confirm this behavior in Ubuntu Studio 18.04 (xfce4). The GUI shows that I'm not a member of my UPG, but for all other groups I am a member of (according to `id`) the membership is displayed correctly. Likely a bug in the GUI.

Comment: It's correct in my Ubuntu MATE 18.04, same settings structure as OP - Properties for my group lists me as a member

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for understanding my confusion...! ;-)

Comment: @Zanna i did exactly the same with Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 as described in the OP and got the same result... (just different GID for `lpadmin` and `sambashare`). :-/

Comment: I'm talking about the GUI, not `/etc/group` which afaik is normal the way you showed. It's the same in mine. The possible weirdness here is the GUI which should show the user in the group (I believe `id` and you can also run `groups` I think)(Also OP is a person and it's you!)

Comment: It looks like the GUI only uses the information from `/etc/groups`. When I use the GUI to add or remove myself to or from my UPG I definitely have a change in `/etc/groups` but no change in the output of `id`.

Comment: @mook765 yes, this is also my assumption... but why is this so? for a reason? a bug? - IMHO the only GUI-item *"Users and Groups"* should list all groups/users/members no matter if primary or supplementary groups nor where they are noted. ...the average GUI-user has no idea of and mostly also no interest in such internals.

Comment: I think the UPG is handled in a special way, I believe one must belong to this group, the UPG is defined in `/etc/passwd`. The GUI is probably meant to manage `/etc/groups` and nothing else. I agree with you that this is confusing, in my opinion we could call it a bug.