# how should `id` and `/etc/group` be read?

Tags: users, user-management, groups

This is a follow-up question to [Why is a user not a member of their private group (UPG)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1069389/354350) although the first question isn't really necessary to understand this one.

---

The command `id` seems pretty clear...

```
test@test ~ $ id test
uid=1000(test) gid=1000(test) groups=1000(test),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),129(sambashare)
```

it shows the UID and GID of `test` (resp. its UPG) and then additionally lists all groups of which the user `test` is a member.

---

But then how should `/etc/group` be read?

```
test@test ~ $ less /etc/group | grep test
adm:x:4:syslog,test
cdrom:x:24:test
sudo:x:27:test
dip:x:30:test
plugdev:x:46:test
lpadmin:x:113:test
test:x:1000:
sambashare:x:129:test
```

The group-name at the beginning is pretty clear and also that the number is the GID; and after that the names of the group-members are listed. But why isn't the second last line `test:x:1000:test` instead of  `test:x:1000:` to indicate, that the user `test` is member of the group `test`?

***bonus question:*** what is the `x` in the second column for?

Comment: `x` indicates groups are password protected or may use encrypted password. The actual password may or may not be set, but there should be entry for that group in /etc/gshadow. As for testuser, it's the group owner. The list should indicate only other users who are members

Comment: See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Introduction_To_System_Administration/s3-acctspgrps-group.html . "X" indicates passwords are shadowed so .... https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/shadow-file-formats.html . There may be more specific Debian/ ubuntu documentation on these files. You have good questions but they are broad

Comment: " But why isn't the second last line test:x:1000:test instead of  test:x:1000: to indicate, that the user test is member of the group test?" because there's no need for that. The `test` user is specified to be a member of `test` group by their `/etc/passwd` entry (which lists only the primary group). Mentioning it in `/etc/group` would just be redundant.

Comment: @muru well, avoiding redundancy may be a main reason as it can cause other problems... you are the first one mentioning this. thanks for your input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in your question

> [id] shows the UID and GID of test (resp. its UPG) and then additionally lists all groups of which the user test is a member.

The line you are asking about:

`test:x:1000:`

`test`, the user, is a member of `test`, the group. This is defined in `/etc/passwd`. The groups in `/etc/passwd` defines the 'primary' group of user `test`. Additional or **supplementary** groups are defined in `/etc/group`: in this case `test` user is also member of `adm`, `cdrom`, `sudo`, etc.

Also see

- https://serverfault.com/a/605838/470077
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152257/105418

As for "why?", I am afraid this may be a UNIX standard. I.e., it was created this way nearly 50 years ago and that's the way it has been done.